# Why the function "onaddstream" is never called?

Tags: webrtc

Hello I followed this tutorial to create a simple webrtc example.
https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/WebRTC-PeerConnection.html .

So look my JFFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/xzspquew/9/
 and tell me please why I can't enter to the function onaddstream ? The console.log("this function is called") is neved called. Why ?

```
    navigator.getUserMedia({audio:false, video:true}, success, error)

var pc = new RTCPeerConnection()
var pc2 = new RTCPeerConnection()

pc.onaddstream = function(event) {
    console.log("this function is called")
    var video2 = document.getElementById("video2")
  video2.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.stream)
  video2.play()
}

document.querySelector("#repondre").addEventListener('click', function repondre() {
  var answer = prompt("Please enter your sdp remote offer");
  console.log(answer)
  pc2.setRemoteDescription(JSON.parse(answer))
    pc2.createAnswer(successanswerrtc, errorrtc)
})

function successanswerrtc(answersdp) {
    pc2.setLocalDescription(answersdp)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(answersdp))
  pc.setRemoteDescription(answersdp)
}

function sucessrtc(offersdp) {
    pc.setLocalDescription(offersdp)
  alert(JSON.stringify(offersdp))
  console.log(JSON.stringify(offersdp))
} 
function errorrtc(err) {
    console.log("error" + err)
}

function success(stream) {
    var video1 = document.getElementById("video1")
  video1.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream)
  video1.play()
  pc.createOffer(sucessrtc, errorrtc)
}
function error() {
    console.log("error")
}
```

Comment: Many things wrong here. What are you trying to do? You have two peer connections, yet you prompt the user to "enter remote offer" and proceed to call it an answer. I can't discern what the goal here is. Connect the two peer connections, or connect to somewhere else?

Answer (score 3):

That tutorial appears to be outdated. Perhaps https://webrtc.org/start/#demos-and-samples

According to MDN documentation, it has been deprecated:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/onaddstream

> This property has been removed from the specification; you should now use RTCPeerConnection.ontrack to watch for track events instead. It is included here in order to help you adapt existing code and understand existing samples, which may not be up-to-date yet.

Comment: I changed but it does not shows the remote video stream in my jsfiddle....

Comment: See my edited answer. Look for newer tutorials, because if the one you're using has a deprecated variable, then the rest of it also might not be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

It looks you are trying with an outdated demo,
Try [this demo](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/pc1/) from WebRTC official [samples](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/)

In your fiddle you didn't handled the candidates & streams properly .
If you are making a call from `pc` to `pc2`, you need to add stream to pc by calling `pc.addstream(stream)` then `pc2.onaddstream` or `pc2.onaddtrack` method will triggered.

I updated your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8mchrc3v/1/

Comment: Look https://jsfiddle.net/xzspquew/10/ I added pc.addstream(stream) but the remote video is not showed