# cannot resolve symbol 'RTCPeerConnection()'

Tags: android, webrtc

I try to solve this issue [Why the function "onaddstream" is never called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43965132/why-the-function-onaddstream-is-never-called)

But it's look like that:

> 'rtcpeerconnection()' doesn't exist in the last version of webrtc :
>   "org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.28513"

My onAddStream has a callback in old version. But not anymore

Please help me

Edit after answer of @philip

I can't override peerObserver, android studio say:

> Expression peerObserver of type 'peerConnection.Observer' cannot be
>   invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found.

```
 override fun runnerConnect(peerObserver: PeerConnection.Observer) {
        Log.d("WebRTCClientCaster", "runnerConnect sdp ")
        //   mCurrentPeerConnection = mPeerConnectionFactory!!.createPeerConnection(IceServer.instance.listServers(), peerObserver)
        val rtcConfig: PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration = PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration(IceServer.instance.listServers())
        rtcConfig.sdpSemantics = PeerConnection.SdpSemantics.UNIFIED_PLAN
        mCurrentPeerConnection = mPeerConnectionFactory!!.createPeerConnection(rtcConfig, peerObserver)
    }

    override fun runnerConnect(sdpObserver: SdpObserver) {
        Log.d("WebRTCClientCaster", "runnerConnect peer")
       // mCurrentPeerConnection!!.addStream(mLocalMS)

        val mVideoTrack =
            mPeerConnectionFactory?.createVideoTrack(WebRTCConstant.VIDEO_ID, mVideoSource)
        mCurrentPeerConnection?.addTransceiver(mVideoTrack)
        val mAudioTrack =
            mPeerConnectionFactory?.createAudioTrack(WebRTCConstant.AUDIO_ID, mAudioSource)
        mCurrentPeerConnection?.addTransceiver(mAudioTrack)
        mCurrentPeerConnection!!.createOffer(sdpObserver, sdpConstraints)
    }
```

The part where I create factory and source :

```
private fun setConfigurationOfCamera() {

        Log.d("webRTCClientCaster", "setConfigurationOfCamera")
        val options = PeerConnectionFactory.Options()
        val defaultVideoEncoderFactory = DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(
            this.mEglBase,
            true,
            true
        )
        val defaultVideoDecoderFactory = DefaultVideoDecoderFactory(this.mEglBase)
        mPeerConnectionFactory = PeerConnectionFactory.builder()
            .setOptions(options)
            .setVideoEncoderFactory(defaultVideoEncoderFactory)
            .setVideoDecoderFactory(defaultVideoDecoderFactory)
            .createPeerConnectionFactory()

        mLocalMS = mPeerConnectionFactory!!.createLocalMediaStream(WebRTCConstant.STREAM_LABEL)

        if (mPeerConnectionParameters.isVideoCallEnabled) {

            val surfaceTextureHelper = SurfaceTextureHelper.create("CaptureThread", this.mEglBase)
            videoCapturerAndroid = Capturer.getInstance().video
            mVideoSource = mPeerConnectionFactory?.createVideoSource(videoCapturerAndroid!!.isScreencast)

            videoCapturerAndroid?.initialize(surfaceTextureHelper, MyApp.getContext(), mVideoSource?.capturerObserver)
            Capturer.getInstance().startCapture(
                mPeerConnectionParameters.videoWidth,
                mPeerConnectionParameters.videoHeight,
                mPeerConnectionParameters.videoFps
            )
            // Add track to video capture with device
            mLocalMS.addTrack(createVideoTrack(WebRTCConstant.VIDEO_ID, mVideoSource!!))
        }

        mAudioSource = mPeerConnectionFactory!!.createAudioSource(audioConstraints)
        mLocalMS.addTrack(createAudioTrack(mAudioSource!!))

        listener.onConfigurationReady()
    }
```

The comment it what I replace, and with this code I Have a sigabrt who say :

```
# Fatal error in: ../../../../usr/local/google/home/sakal/code/webrtc-aar-release/src/pc/peer_connection.cc, line 1240
    # last system error: 0
    # Check failed: !IsUnifiedPlan()
    # AddStream is not available with Unified Plan SdpSemantics. Please use AddTrack instead.
2019-09-23 12:53:07.223 4804-6057/com.Dazzl.debug A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 6057 (signaling_threa)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this. Note that onTrack is implemented in the PeerConnectionObserver (pcObserver), not the the peerConnection itself:

```
    PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration rtcConfig =
            new PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration(mIceServers);
rtcConfig.sdpSemantics = PeerConnection.SdpSemantics.UNIFIED_PLAN;
//Unified Plan is the new standard for SDP semantics and is needed to use transceivers

peerConnection = factory.createPeerConnection(rtcConfig, new PcObserver("localPeerCreation")
        {
            @Override
            public void onTrack(RtpTransceiver transceiver) {
                showToast(getString(R.string.onReceivedTrackToastMessage));
                super.onTrack(transceiver);
                gotRemoteTrack(transceiver);
            }
        });

//Somewhere else in your code, where you create the local video track...
localVideoTrack = factory.createVideoTrack(VIDEO_TRACK_ID, videoSource);

peerConnection.addTransceiver(localVideoTrack);
peerConnection.addTransceiver(localAudioTrack);
```

//In a separate class create a PeerConnectionObserver that inherits from PeerConnection.Observer...

```
  public class PcObserver implements PeerConnection.Observer {
    private String logTag;

    CustomPeerConnectionObserver(String logTag) {
        this.logTag = logTag
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignalingChange(PeerConnection.SignalingState signalingState) {
        Log.d(logTag, "onSignalingChange() called with: signalingState = [" + signalingState + "]");
    }
 //....
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying me, maybe I was not clear but my problem is RTCPeerConnection doesn't exist in webrtc android. In android there a class PeerConnection but she doesn't implement ontrack.

Comment: Oh I see, it looks like onTrack is implemented in the PeerConnectionObserver, not the peerConnection itself. I will update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that to use onTrack you will have to use UNIFIED_PLAN sdp semantics in your RTC config. Will edit answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for take time for this. I edit my post with what you say, I explain my new issu here.

Comment: You're welcome. Does your peerObserver class implement PeerConnection.Observer? Also, AddStream can't be used in UnifiedPlan Sdp semantics. It's the old way. the new way is to do peerConnection.addTransceiver(videoTrack) or I guess you could do peerConnection.addTrack(videoTrack)

Comment: It's possible the error "Expression peerObserver of type 'peerConnection.Observer' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found." is because of a syntax error since in the code sample you wrote "peerObserver{}"

Comment: So have an other issue with that way, my offer is different that the old way, then when I get the answer, the onSetFailure method say "Failed to set remote answer sdp: The order of m-lines in answer doesn't match order in offer. Rejecting answer."
the difference is instead of ` a=group:BUNDLE audio video` , I have ` a=group:BUNDLE 1 0`.

Comment: I guess the difference is because you are now using UNIFED_PLAN sdp semantics. So on other side of the connection I guess it should also use unified plan. But I'm not sure what is on the other side of your connection.

Comment: okey, I fix this, but how you can override in a function call that don't work for me...

Comment: Oh sorry, when I originally posted my code I changed it a little. Actually you should make a constructor call in the code for a new PcObserver, and in the constructor call you can override it. I've updated my answer accordingly.